# jQuery submit form dosen't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, but the form won't submit.
Any ideas why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var p = document.createElement("input");
    $("#login_form").append(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password);
    $("#password").val('');
    $("#login_form").submit();
});    
});
```

The value of #password does reset to nothing, so the ID's correct.

Comment: please share jsfillde or html code.

Comment: Do you really need to prevent default behaviour which seems to be what you want to do anyway???

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `e.preventDefault();`, It prevents form submission so you should remove `e.preventDefault();`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var p = document.createElement("input");
        $("#login_form").append(p);
        p.name = "p";
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.value = hex_sha512(password);
        $("#password").val('');
    });      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The form doesn't submit because you've got `e.preventDefault` in there to stop the submission. You're then triggering the `submit` event again, and getting caught in a recursive cycle.

Remove `e.preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `e.preventDefault();` , it will prevent the form submission even trigger submit event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_form").submit(function(){    
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var p = document.createElement("input");
        $("#login_form").append(p);
        p.name = "p";
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.value = hex_sha512(password);
        $("#password").val('');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the native submit after you've made the changes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var p = document.createElement("input");

        p.name = "p";
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.value = hex_sha512(password);

        $("#login_form").append(p);
        $("#password").val('');

        this.submit(); // native handler
    });    
});
```

Triggering the native submit after the hidden input is inserted makes sure it's there when the form is submitted.